# List of Seforim that are mentioned in the Pischei Teshuva

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, responsa

In his [hakdamah](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x3471), the Pischei Teshuva lists off 192  seforim that he used in his sefer.
Did anybody ever publish a comprehensive collection of all the seforim that are used in the Pischei Teshuva, either in the order of the Shulchan Aruch or all the relevant teshuvos from that particular sefer (e.g. you will have all the Shu''t Maharshal that he brings down in one place)?

Comment: Are you asking if someone published a book that is a collection of all the passages cited by the Pischei Teshuva?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking - you're referring us to a list of the Seforim he used, and then you ask if anybody ever published such a list?